# Сборка библиотеки VLC-Qt из исходников

Tags: qt, cmake, mingw, vlc

**Имеем:**

1. Исходники vlc-qt: https://github.com/vlc-qt/vlc-qt
2. Пример (от создателя библиотеки): https://github.com/vlc-qt/examples/tree/master/simple-player

**Задча:**

Заставить пример компилироваться)

Несмотря на наличие инструкции по сборке (BUILDING.md) столкнулся с проблемами при сборке на Windows (на Ubuntu всё собралось без проблем). Согласно инструкции по сборке для Windows порядок действий следующий:

```
$ md build
$ cd build
$ cmake .. -GNinja -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ^
  -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="E:/install/vlc-qt/msvc64" ^
  -DLIBVLC_LIBRARY="E:/vlc/win64/sdk/lib/libvlc.lib" ^
  -DLIBVLCCORE_LIBRARY="E:/vlc/win64/sdk/lib/libvlccore.lib" ^
  -DLIBVLC_INCLUDE_DIR="E:/vlc/win64/sdk/include"
$ ninja
$ ninja install
```

Но никаких пояснений - откуда берется директория с sdk, что за DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX (хотя, здесь логично предположить, что это путь, куда будет установлена готовая библиотека) в BUILD.md - нет. Пробовал подключать библиотеки libvlcore.lib и libvlc.lib видеоплеера VLC и прочих сторонних сборок - пока безрезультатно. Собирать пытаюсь на Windows 10 для Qt 5.14 как через cmake для MSVC64 (пример из инструкции), так и для MinGW32/Mingw-w64 через cmake-gui (руками инициализируя переменные/пути/префиксы)

Comment: по поводу `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` - ваши предположения верны, эта стандартная переменная `cmake`, смотрите подробнее в оффициальной документации. Что же касается `sdk`, то, смею предположить, это директория из `vlc`, который, согласно документации, у вас должен быть установлен перед сборкой проекта

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, Благодарю за участие. Предмет был изучен подробнее, более конкретизированный вопрос (с логом ошибки) я задал на англоязычном ресурсе: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61455331/building-vlc-qt-library-from-sources , решений этой проблемы я так и не нашёл, воспользовался статичной сборкой с официального сайта VLC.